# Robolectric compilation error while using shadowOf method

Tags: android, robolectric

I am using Robolectric 1.2 in an Andorid 2.3.3 project (API 10)
It throws the below compilation error, when using shadowOf method

```
ShadowView shadowView = Robolectric.shadowOf(view);
```

error: cannot access ObjectAnimator

But the error is gone, if I change the android sdk to API 11 and above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some analysis, found that it is a bug in robolectric.

For now, using 2.0-alpha-1 seems to fix the issue.

Here is the github issue created for the issue
https://github.com/pivotal/robolectric/issues/431

Answer (score 3):

I'm still having this issue with 2.2.  I got around this by

```
import static org.robolectric.Robolectric.shadowOf_;
...
ShadowView shadowView = Robolectric.shadowOf_(view);
```

If anyone could provide some insight why this works, that would be awesome!